# In VSTS Task Groups is it possible to parameterise a checkbox

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

One of the tasks in my Task Group has a checkbox. Is it possible to set it as a parameter?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a possible workaround has been discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1656). Does it help you in any way?

Comment: I don't understand how. They discuss tasks development. In my case, it's a Task Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the feature is not available. But it's already added in our backlog.

And you can also refer the user voice [Allow Task Group parameters to be optional](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20399509-allow-task-group-parameters-to-be-optional) for the feature suggestion.